# Automatically match output file with input file (Applescript x FFMPEG)

Tags: ffmpeg, applescript, automator, video-encoding, subtitle

I use the following AppleScript as an Automator Service to right click a video file in the finder and burn in a matching subtitle file (.ass) with an ffmpeg terminal command. In this case ffmpeg encodes a new Prores 422(HQ) file.

```
on run {input, parameters}
tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    set filesString to ""
    repeat with file_ in input
        set filesString to filesString & " " & quoted form of (POSIX path of file_)
    end repeat
    do script "for f in" & filesString & "; do  
base=$f  
ffmpeg -y -i \"$base\" -c:v prores -profile:v 3 -pix_fmt yuv422p10le -vf \"ass=${base%.*}.ass\" -c:a copy \"${base%.*}_sub.mov\";
done"
    end tell
    return input
end run
```

Would it be possible to automatically match the output file and it's codec to the input file?
We use a lot of different input formats due to a mixed windows / mac environment (Prores (mov), dnxhr (mxf/mov)) and I would like to not have 8-12 encoding options in the finder service menu's of the workstations :).

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ffmpeg will choose the codec itself from the file ending, if not given as parameter. In most cases this is fine. Simply set the same extension from the input file to the output file.

If you need more granularity, you can use `ffprobe`. It's a tool from ffmpeg and can read all properties of a video file.

A good explanation can be found here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips

For example, the codec of the first stream (this is the video stream in most video files) can be read via:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```

You can save the values in variables and set them in the ffmpeg command.